# How do you integrate $9^{\sin x}$?

Tags: calculus, integration

I understand how you would differentiate it, but how would you integrate it?
After plugging it into integral calculator, it says that it is non-elemetary, what does this mean too?

Comment: It means it cannot be expressed in terms of standard mathematical functions.

Comment: This is a useful lesson for you.  **Most** formulas you can write down have only non-elementary integrals.  Indefinite integrals with closed-form answers are the exceptions, not the rule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not have any closed-form. What we know is
$$\int _{x=0}^{2\pi} 9^{\sin(x)} \mathrm{d} x=\int _{x=0}^{2\pi} e^{\ln(9)\sin(x)} \mathrm{d} x=\mathrm{I}_0(\ln(9)),$$
where $\mathrm{I}_0(\cdot)$ is the [modified Bessel function of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).